# No System Tray Detected

Tags: 12.04, 13.04, printing, hp

Ok, I realize this question has been answered, but none of those answers are complete so maybe my I will have better luck.  I have to machines, one running Ubuntu 12.04LTS, and one current with Ubuntu 13.04.  Both are running the most current version of HPLIP available. I can't stress that enough.  Both versions of HPLIP are current.  Every time I start either machine I get this annoying NO System Tray Detected error. I understand, through researching the issue, that I apparently need to set a delay somewhere.  However, none of the answers given actually explain HOW to accomplish this.  Any clarity on this would be greatly appreciated.  Potentially relevant:  Both are running Cairo Dock.  I'm not sure if that matters as the problem is clearly not limited to those running Cairo Dock, but better too much info than not enough.

Answer (score 2):

Steps to follow for the complete solution of this annoying problem:

1. From the terminal run:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/xdg/autostart/hplip-systray.desktop
   ```
2. Add one # character at the beginning of the line: `Exec=hp-systray -x`
   (If you have HPLIP continue reading.)
3. Save the document and then open the "startup options" (one click in the Ubuntu wheel and search for the specific line).
4. Edit the HP System Tray Service.
5. Change that command with hp-toolbox.
6. Save changes and restart the computer.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue unpluging my mouse when booting. I meant to boot without the mouse, the message "no system tray detected" is not shown. I use Ubuntu 12.04 and HPLIP 3.14.6.